# How to ensure order of events in message groups with amqp reactive-messaging and quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, amqp, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Is there a way to make amqp reactive-messaging and quarkus ensure order of events in message groups?

There is my implementation next, and I can see that inbox-events subscriber can observe multiple events within one message group, and that's not exactly what I had expected.

In my opinion, the next message in a group should come only after acknowledging the prev one.

**Consumer**

```
@Channel("inbox-events") Multi<Long> inboxEvents;
...
inboxEvents
    .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(this::handleEvent)
    .subscribe()
    .with(eventId -> {
        log.info("Event was handled, id={}", eventId);
    });
```

**Producer**

```
@Channel("outbox-events") MutinyEmitter<Long> outboxEventsEmitter;
...
final var metadata = OutgoingAmqpMetadata.builder()
    .withGroupId(String.valueOf(groupId))
    .build();
final var message = Message.of(id)
    .addMetadata(metadata);
return outboxEventsEmitter.sendMessage(message);
```

**application.properties**

```
mp.messaging.incoming.inbox-events.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.incoming.inbox-events.address=DISPATCHING
mp.messaging.outgoing.outbox-events.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.outgoing.outbox-events.durable=true
mp.messaging.outgoing.outbox-events.address=DISPATCHING
```

Comment: Can you try trandormToUniAndConcatenate instead ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried transformToUniAndConcatenate() method too, it guarantees order but within all incoming events without any concurrency for different groups (just one by one). It's not my case, I need concurrent handling for different groups. (If you also wish to play with that - there is my example - https://github.com/crionuke/reactive-amqp-with-groups)

Comment: Consumer groups is not a functionality of Mutiny but of your message broker. You either have to configure it in your broker settings or in reactive messaging, see for example this link: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/4.9.0/amqp/amqp/

Comment: btw, I have a working example of consumer groups with Redis Streams & Mutiny. The code is quite old, but it works and maybe it can be of help to you:

https://github.com/Serkan80/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/redis-streams-quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP clients do not provide any parallelism by message group id out of the box.

You therefore need to manually dispatch event processing to a worker thread pool to process events in parallel. Mutiny APIs allow to do such operations. You can couple that with the [KeyedMulti](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/latest/concepts/keyed-multi/) support to group messages by group id (available since Reactive Messaging 4.6.0).

Here is a sample code :

```java
    @Incoming("data")
    @Outgoing("sink")
    Multi<Integer> process(KeyedMulti<String, Integer> group) {
        return group
                .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
                .map(i -> {
                    String id = group.key();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20L * i);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return i + 1;
                });
    }

    @ApplicationScoped
    static class AmqpKeyValueExtractor implements KeyValueExtractor {

        @Override
        public boolean canExtract(Message<?> first, Type keyType, Type valueType) {
            return first.getMetadata(IncomingAmqpMetadata.class).isPresent();
        }

        @Override
        public Object extractKey(Message<?> message, Type keyType) {
            return message.getMetadata(IncomingAmqpMetadata.class)
                    .map(IncomingAmqpMetadata::getGroupId)
                    .orElse(null);
        }

        @Override
        public Object extractValue(Message<?> message, Type valueType) {
            return message.getPayload();
        }
    }
```

The `KeyValueExtractor` is self-explanatory, for each incoming message the code extracts a key and a value to be used in `KeyedMulti`.

The `process` method will be called for each new group id, and the method will use `runSubscriptionOn` to run the processing on a worker thread pool (You cannot use `@Blocking` annotation in this scenario).

You'll notice that while the message order is preserved inside a group, it'll happen concurrently across all groups.